# Loading data at the end of my table with ajax

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a page where I display companies. I have a lot of companies so I would like to display only the first 20 and allow the user to click on a link ("Load more") at the end of the table. Clicking on this link should keep existing companies and add newly loaded companies at the end of **the table**.

**How can I accomplish this?** I know I had to work with ajax and partial views but I cannot imagine keeping actual companies in my table (not erasing these companies when loading new ones).

Maybe there is an ajax option telling to not erase content (of a targetID) **but** loading data at the end?

Is there an example to give me some concrete idea?

Thanks.

---

UPDATED

Here is a problem I encountered with jQuery icons on newly loaded rows. How can I proceed to have newly loaded rows (ajax get) with icons?

[image]

Here is my javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    // Set icons on edit & delete buttons
    $(".editCompany").button({ icons: { primary: "ui-icon-pencil"} });
    $(".deleteCompany").button({ icons: { primary: "ui-icon-trash"} });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set the ajaxOptions insertion mode to InsertAfter.

InsertionMode.InsertAfter instead of InsertionMode.Replace and make sure you are targetting the table.

Something like this:

```
@Ajax.ActionLink("Load More...", "Action", new AjaxOptions{ UpdateTargetId="myTable", InsertionMode = InsertionMode.InsertAfter })
```

You'll need to make sure that you are returning a PartialView that only renders `<tr>` elements, so that they properly insert the rows.

A link to the enumeration of possible values for InsertionMode:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.ajax.insertionmode.aspx

For the jQuery Icons to resolve you just need to make sure you apply the same jQuery in the OnComplete callback of the AjaxOptions.

```
new AjaxOptions{ UpdateTargetId="myTable", InsertionMode = InsertionMode.InsertAfter, OnComplete = 'LoadIcons()' }
```

Comment: Thank you Banford, I try it immediately

Comment: I try it and rows are loaded successfully. Just une question (out of scope) I noticed that my jQuery icons are not showed on newly loaded rows. This is because these icons are (normally) defined at $(document).ready(function()... Any idea how can I display these icons on newly loaded rows? I updated my question to show a screenshot of the view. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Extract them from your document load javascript into a javascript function on its own. You can then call this from the OnComplete property in the AjaxOptions. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.ajax.ajaxoptions.aspx